# Debugging hooks that fired?

Tags: debugging

I'm somewhat new to module development.

Is there a way to currently output what hooks have been run on certain nodes?

Would this be done with xdebug?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unless you get a fatal error (or blank screen) it's pretty easy to get a list of modules that will invoked when a special hook is called:

```
$modules = module_implements($hook);
foreach ($modules as $key =>  $module) {
  $function = $module . '_' . $hook;
  if (!function_exists($function)) {
    unset($modules[$key]);
  }
}
// $modules is now an array containing all the modules that will be invoked by $hook.
```

You could use stuff like xDebug to track the flow of the Drupal, but this can be overwhelming, especially if you are new to Drupal.

Comment: If you would like to try debugging and don't want to spend hours setting it up, you can try [Quickstart](http://drupal.org/project/quickstart). It is a virtual machine and with drush it is very easy to setup a site, then put in your module, import in Netbeans and hit debug.

Comment: Wouldn't this just show all modules that implement a particular hook, not all hooks that have Drupal has called up to that point?  The later is how I read @chrisjlee's request.

Comment: @MPD It will not just show which modules implement a hook but also the order in which they are called. If the context is what happens before/after my module's hook is called, the above will suffice. If you wanted to figure out if hook foo is called at a certain moment in the execution flow, it will be quite hard to figure out, since Drupal is so complex. Especially for a new developer. I'm unsure if this is what OP needs, but it's probably more useful than any xDebug suggestions anyways.